# react js: not able to write this in react class componet

Tags: reactjs

what is the equivelant of this code in class componet? I am able to write this only in react hook (functional component)

```
setState({ ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

I am able to  multiple values passed from multiple forms  to this setDataState in functional componet
I want the same in class componet but this syntax is not working

currently, I have it written like this. This changes every text field that has changehandler

```
 changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ allValues: e.target.value });
  };
```

entire code

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";
export default class Addmedicine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isDone: true, allValues: "" };
    this.medicineClose = this.medicineClose.bind(this);
  }

  medicineClose() {
    this.setState({ isDone: false });
  }
  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ allValues: e.target.value });
  };

  submitValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

    var object = {};
    formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
      object[key] = value;
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify(object);

    formData.append("data", json);

    const headers = {
      Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    };
    axios
      .post(
        "posturl",
        formData,
        {
          headers: headers,
        }
      )
      .then(() => {
        alert("Medicine was submitted");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Cannot add Medicine again");
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.isDone ? (
          <div style={styles.module}>
            <h2 style={{ margin: "0px" }}>Add New Medicine</h2>
            <hr style={{ color: "#fff" }} />
            <form onSubmit={this.submitValue}>
              <table
                style={{ borderCollapse: "seperate", borderSpacing: "0em 1em" }}
              >
                <tr style={styles.tr}>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>Morning Before Food</td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="medicationTime"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      defaultValue="morning before food"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      value={this.state.allValues}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>

            <form onSubmit={this.submitValue}>
              <table
                style={{ borderCollapse: "seperate", borderSpacing: "0em 1em" }}
              >
                <tr style={styles.tr}>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>Morning After Food</td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="medicationTime"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      defaultValue="morning after food"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      value={this.state.allValues}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>

            <form onSubmit={this.submitValue}>
              <table
                style={{ borderCollapse: "seperate", borderSpacing: "0em 1em" }}
              >
                <tr style={styles.tr}>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>Afternoon Before Food</td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="medicationTime"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      defaultValue="afternoon before food"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      value={this.state.allValues}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>

            <form onSubmit={this.submitValue}>
              <table
                style={{ borderCollapse: "seperate", borderSpacing: "0em 1em" }}
              >
                <tr style={styles.tr}>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>Afternoon After Food</td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="medicationTime"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      defaultValue="afternoon after aood"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      value={this.state.allValues}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>

            <form onSubmit={this.submitValue}>
              <table
                style={{ borderCollapse: "seperate", borderSpacing: "0em 1em" }}
              >
                <tr style={styles.tr}>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>Night Before Food</td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="medicationTime"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      defaultValue="night before food"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      value={this.state.allValues}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>

            <form onSubmit={this.submitValue}>
              <table
                style={{ borderCollapse: "seperate", borderSpacing: "0em 1em" }}
              >
                <tr style={styles.tr}>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>Night After Food</td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="medicationTime"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      defaultValue="night after food"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      style={styles.label}
                      onChange={this.changeHandler}
                      value={this.state.allValues}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.tdstyle}>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

Comment: this has made all my text field non typable

Comment: Provide more code. you asked just for setting state. @MeenuKs

Comment: i have posted entire code now

Comment: use a `value={this.state.<INPUT_NAME>}` for each input. @MeenuKs

Comment: good luck @MeenuKs

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> changeHandler = (e) => {
>   this.setState({ allValues: e.target.value });
> };
> ```

This will save all updates to `this.state.allValues` property, which likely isn't what you are after if you are trying to use dynamic state updates.

The syntax will be very similar to the function component state update with a minor difference, class component's setState handles the shallow merging of the root state properties so you don't need to manage this manually yourself (*only more deeply nested state would need to be shallow copied*).

```
changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

Comment: this has made all my text field non typable

Comment: @MeenuKs What text are you referring to? Your question was about setting state in a class component. Have you not included all the relevant code in your question you are asking about? Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are your input values nested in `this.state.allValues`?

Comment: i have posted entire code now

Comment: @MeenuKs You've several forms that give all inputs the same name, there's no way do differentiate them so they all use the same state. Give each input a unique name and use `this.state.<uniqueName` as the input `value`. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-not-able-to-write-this-in-react-class-componet-069o2) fork of your code.